# Is it possible to see different forms of a word through the Word API?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word

Is it possible to see a different form of a word through the Word API? I am making an *Open Source* tool that automatically adds documentation to properties and methods when saving the document. It will only do it to methods that are public or protected.

I want that if you follow a specific naming convention and use (for instance) the method name `AddPerson` or `add_person`, the code takes these method names and converts them into an array of words. "Add" and "Person".

From these words, I would like to detect if it is a verb or a noun. For instance, in this example, "Add" is a verb and "Person" is a noun.

Once this has been detected, I would like to transform the words, to form the following documentation statement:

> **AddPerson**(Person person)
>
> Adds a person.
>
> *person*: The person.

How can I convert "Add" into "Adds", and how can I detect if "Add" is a verb or a noun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a `System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.PluralizationService` from the Entity Framework which does the job perfectly fine.

The project can be found here:

http://todoc.codeplex.com/

Still working on it though.